# dynamic arrays and flexible arrays

Tags: arrays, programming-languages, dynamic-arrays, flexible-array-member

what is the difference between those two types of arrays, thanks in advance for any good example taken from different languages

Comment: Specifying language might help, because most of them have no concept of 'flexible arrays' (whatever it might be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C/C++ a flexible array is a member of a struct that is an array (not just a pointer) but doesn't specify a length ([reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/strct.htm)). As such, a struct with a flexible array is an incomplete type, so the typeof operator can't be used.

A dynamic array is an ordered collection (list) that can grow and shrink. Dynamic arrays are usually implemented as a linked list or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic arrays have values that can be changed by code and more values populated. The flexible array is an array that does not have a hard coded limit to its length.